# Multiple Spring scheduled tasks triggered at the same time

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I have multiple scheduled tasks, triggered by a CRON expression, at the same time:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 3 * * MON")
public void weeklyReport() {...}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 3 * * *")
public void dailyReport() {...}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 00 5 * * MON")
public void weeklyEmail() {...}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 00 5 * * *")
public void dailyEmail() {...}
```

`dailyReport` and `dailyEmail` are scheduled every day at 3:30am and 5:00am respectively.

`weeklyReport` and `weeklyEmail` are scheduled every monday at 3:30am and 5:00am respectively.

The issue occurs on monday, when there are two tasks (supposed to be) triggered.

In my case, `weeklyReport` is never triggered, but `weeklyEmail` and `dailyEmail`, which are both scheduled at 5:00am, are successfully triggered.

I need to precise that I don't override the pool size (default is 1).

My questions are:

- What is the execution order when the pool size is 1 and multiple tasks should be triggered at the same time?
- Do you have any idea why one of the scheduled tasks is not triggered?